# backup visual studio folder and sql database

Tags: backups

I like to backup things every night or say every week. I'm sure there's a more efficient way than emailing the solution folder and database files to myself! I don't have team foundation or any commercial products like that. I'm looking for a freeware.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the question, I'm guessing you don't use a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). There are a number to choose from and some are better suited for different things, but either [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) or [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) are two strong options. The advantage to version control is that it allows you to track how your code changes, see the differences and easily step back if you need to.

As for actual back ups, there are a number of programs that will do regular back ups of directories so you are not in trouble if your hard drive dies. Here is a [list of software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) that range from a manual process you can execute when you want and just puts a copy in another location to a full fledged automated system that will do everything and provide restore points. This all works on the more general backups of any file. The revision control I talked about earlier is geared more directly to source files and will be a bigger benefit.

Comment: Mercurial is another good option for version control (and, from my understanding, is more Windows-friendly than Git, but still has the advantages Git has over SVN). If you really feel like being a nerd, you could write a script to push your version control commits to a remote repository automatically at set times/intervals. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing quite often actually.  I have a two step process:

**1) Backup the database to a child directory in the project folder**

**2) Backup the project folder to disk**

It really is a very, *very* quick process that isn't even worth a double-take.  If you don't have version control, and especially if you are a sole-developer on the project, I don't see any issue with this.  I recommend keeping a history of about a week of progress (maybe more or less depending on how fast the project is getting developed).

Answer (score 0):

Either get a free SVN server for code & related stuff or get a generic backup software that can store files where you want (I user [GFI Backup](http://www.gfi.com/downloads/register.aspx?pid=bkupf) and an external HDD for pictures & stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Assembla.com. Set up a free private space. Select a version control system of your preference. Each your commit can be treated as a backup.